# Is there a Liquid Crystal film that is transparent without power applied, and various levels of opaque with power applied?

Tags: windows

Looking to put film on house windows in place of blinds, etc, that allows control of light, hence heat, entering my home, with an app (The app I can handle development of). Similar to the electronic blinds available, but cooler, and a certain design style.

However want it to fail safe (i.e., clear, not fail such that the glass can't be seen out of until replacement film, or driving electronics, can be repaired/sourced). Removing the film is an option, yes, but not ideal from a asthetic point of view with wires to connect to the film hanging, and if installed at some family members place, having to visit to remove the film, and then revisit to install new film.

Have found https://www.gauzy.com/pdlc-smart-glass but alas this Liquid Crystal film is the opposite (100% opaque when not powered).

Does such a Liquid Crystal film exist?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer to the question as asked is "no, but you might want to look at electrochromic options". The longer answer requires to take a tour through the available technologies.

I am going to only include active technologies, i.e. those where you control the state through current. There are passive technologies as well which change state based on temperature (thermochromic) or illumination (photochromic). Also, depending on your use case, you might be better off investigating low-e glass/films, which do not change state but allow to do some solar control. However, the answer is already long as-is, and I assume you want something that can be controlled in the same manner as blinds (i.e. the user can decide what state they want).

At the time of this writing, ["Everything you want to know about smart glass"](https://learn.gauzy.com/hubfs/Everything_You_Want_To_Know_About_Smart_Glass_PDF.pdf) from Gauzy (a manufacturer) is in my opinion the best non-technical source available online for these topics; Wikipedia articles are not complete, hard to read, and split the information in many different places.

### High/low transmittance vs. transparent/opaque

First of all, I will distinguish between two related but different properties of windows (and glass in general).

How much energy of the light goes through is quantified by the *transmittance*: the fraction of how much hits on one side vs. how much goes through on the other. In what follows, I will use loosely the term "high-transmittance" to refer to a system that lets through a high amount of energy. Before committing to buying anything, though, you should definitely look at the specs and pay attention that there are *two* values of transmittance to consider (which unfortunately do not have standardized names between US, Europe, etc.):

- [visible transmittance](https://info.glass.com/glass-dictionary/visible-transmittance/) is transmittance in the visible spectrum. It matters for aesthetics and glare - *usually*, you would want a window to look as "transparent" (high-transmittance) as possible.
- the [solar gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_gain) is transmittance averaged over the whole solar spectrum. That is different from visible transmittance because solar radiation contains quite a bit of infrared. That is the value that matters when it comes to temperature.

The other characteristic is about whether you can see what happens on the other side of the glass, i.e. whether it is *opaque* or *transparent*. A system can be opaque even if it lets through a large quantity of light, if that light is diffused (i.e. light bounces around inside, and objects ). For instance [this greenhouse glass](https://www.yuhua-glass.com/glass/diffuse-glass-75-haze.html) lets through almost all energy, but it diffuses the light to spread out the energy and not burn leaves; it is partially opaque (you can still see fuzzy outlines on the objects).

The two properties are distinct, even though they are correlated (at very low-transmittance, a system is necessarily opaque; and it’s hard to do systems systems with very high opacity and very high transmittance).

Now for the technologies for changing light transmission properties in response to electrical stimulation:

### Polymer-dispersed liquid crystals (PDLC)

PDLC, which you mentioned in your post, is one of them. It is opaque when unpowered and transparent when powered. The transparent state is achieved by aligning particles with an electric field; whereas disordered particles make the film opaque. Due to how their technology works, it is not possible to do the same in reverse (i.e. default-transparent) (so the literal answer to the question asked is "no").

Even without the limitation of default-opaque, PDLC is marketed for its quick opaque/transparent transition. You would definitely need to check that it does the high/low transmission switch as well (that is what you need for temperature control). The ones I checked are decent in that regard (solar gain goes from 90-95% to ~20%), though obviously the low-transmission state is not as good as what a low-e glass would achieve.

### Suspended particle devices (SPD)

The key features are the same as PDLC (default partially-opaque, instantaneous switching). It might be very different under the hood, but I don’t see anything that a user should care much about.

### Electrochromic devices (ECD)

That, on the other hand, is a radically different technology. [Electrochromic devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochromic_device) induce a reversible chemical transformation which changes from a high-transmission to a low-transmission state and back.

The high-transmission state at best resembles clear glass, and the low-transmission state at best resembles tinted glass. As of 2022, most available products have a good high-transmission state (>80% transmission). The low-transmission state is fairly variable though, and you should definitely arrange to see a demo of the products before buying. Reading the specs is not enough, because humans perceive light in a non-linear way - the difference between a 20% and a 30% transmission is much larger than the difference between a 30% and a 40% transmission. Even the best low-transmission states are still fairly transparent (no diffusion, and usually >10% transmission), and therefore not usable for applications that require privacy.

Switching requires current, holding the current state does not. In that aspect it is better than the default-opaque that the question complains about, but the system can still be stuck in the low-transmission state while waiting for repairs. It is up to you to decide whether that is acceptable or not; I suspect it will depend a lot on the home, orientation and so on.

Finally, while the PDLC and SPD switch instantaneously, those take ~30min to transition from one state to another. Depending on your preferences (or your family’s), this can either be a dealbreaker ("I cannot replace my blinds with that") or a trifle ("I will program them to switch on/off at given times of the day").

### Film or window?

The main market for those is new buildings, so they come as full glazing units (= windows). Of course, having to change the whole window when installing / maintaining is annoying (harder/longer, more pricey).

A search for "PLDC film" reveals a large market for PLDC refurbishing films. However, I could not find a single EDC film for sale (all results for "electrochromic film" are PLDCs). I assume those do not exist (yet?) because of technical limitations.

Comment: I suspect the reason you can't find ECD films is that most common ECD technologies use either a liquid electrolyte between two rigid (glass/ITO) plates or a solid (rigid, metal-oxide) electrolyte. Flexible ECDs seem to be a topic of [active research and development](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.solmat.2022.111709) at the moment, possibly not yet commercial.